# adding a record to existing aws cognito dataset

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I can create a single record with a new identity dataset using the code below.

```
// Create a record in a dataset and synchronize with the server
            var updateRequest = new UpdateRecordsRequest
            {
                DatasetName = DataSetName,
                RecordPatches = new List<RecordPatch>
                {
                    new RecordPatch
                    {
                        Op = Operation.Replace,
                        SyncCount = 0,
                        Key = user.Email,
                        Value = user.Password
                    }
                },
                SyncSessionToken = recordsResult.SyncSessionToken
            };
```

I want to only have one identity dataset. How can I add a record to an existing identity dataset?

Answer (score 2):

The process is similar to what you are doing to put the initial entry into the dataset. Create a RecordPatch for the new key value pair and call UpdateRecords with a SyncSessionToken from ListRecords.  Keep in mind you can supply multiple record patches at the same time.  The SyncCount on the RecordPatch should be the SyncCount of the Record from ListRecords, or 0 if it doesn't yet exist.  If you are using .NET, depending on your environment, it may be easier to use the high level sdk which allows you to treat your dataset like a hash table that you can put and get strings from and call SynchronizeAsync() when you want to push your updates to the server to make them available to other devices.  [.NET high level Cognito Sync SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sync-data.html)